# Why are these two MongoDB queries different?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm a MongoDB newbie.

Given this document:

```
{ "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
```

This query matches it:

```
{ "$and" : [ {"y" : 1}, {"$or" : [ {"x" : 1}, {"x" : 5} ] } ] }
```

but this one does not:

```
{ "y" : 1, "$or" : [ {"x" : 1}, {"x" : 5} ] }
```

Is there a reason why?

Taking this a bit further:

I can simplify the query to a "degenerate" $or case:

```
{ "y" : 1, "$or" : [ {"x" : 5} ] }
```

And it still doesn't match.  But this one does:

```
{ "y" : 1, "x" : 5 }
```

And so does this one:

```
{ "$or" : [ { "y" : 1 } ], "$or" : [ { "x" : 5 } ] }
```

In general, it seems that when a top-level query document has multiple predicates inside it, they are treated as an implicit AND.  This seems consistent with the documentation.

But if the predicates in that "top-level implicit AND" are a mixture of logicals ($and/$or) with literal comparisons (y:1), then it "fails".

But the same set of predicates inside an explicit $and will "succeed".

I'm just wondering if this behavior is expected, and if so, why.

Comment: I should perhaps have specified that I am using Mongo 2.6.7.

Comment: tested on v2.6.8 and I don't think there is no major change in 2.6.8. See [Release Notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/release-notes/2.6/#release-notes-for-mongodb-2-6)

Comment: To clarify, are you seeing different results than I am ("All those queries worked for me")?  Or are you confirming that you see the same results that I do ("I can reproduce")?

Comment: Ooops.  Just saw your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All those queries worked.

```
> db.test.drop()
true
> db.test.insert({ "x" : 5, "y" : 1 })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.find({ "$and" : [ {"y" : 1}, {"$or" : [ {"x" : 1}, {"x" : 5} ] } ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f20e0a0d484029bca053c4"), "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
> db.test.find({ "y" : 1, "$or" : [ {"x" : 1}, {"x" : 5} ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f20e0a0d484029bca053c4"), "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
> db.test.find({ "y" : 1, "$or" : [ {"x" : 5} ] })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54f20e0a0d484029bca053c4"), "x" : 5, "y" : 1 }
```

Comment: <grumble>  I had not tried this in the mongo shell, and I can't reproduce there either.  The results I describe in the question were happening in a little test app using the C driver.  The behavior is still strange, but now it could be due to a problem in the C driver or the C implementation of libbson or in my test app.  So, er, nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody sees this later, here is what was going on:

In short, when using the mongo C driver, the queries which "failed" were never actually being sent to the Mongo server.  And I never noticed this because I was failing to check for an error.

My code looked like this:

```
mongoc_cursor_t *cursor = mongoc_collection_find(whatever);
const bson_t   *doc_mongo = NULL;
while (mongoc_cursor_next(cursor, &doc_mongo))
{
    whatever
}
```

But after that, I needed to have something like the following snippet to see the error message:

```
if (mongoc_cursor_error (cursor, &error))
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Failed to iterate all documents: %s\n", error.message);
}
```

And the error message I would have seen looked something like this:

```
"Cannot mix top-level query with dollar keys such as..."
```

And the fix was to always wrap the query document in another document under the key "$query".

```
bson_t* wrap(bson_t* q)
{
    bson_t *b = bson_new ();
    bson_append_document(b, "$query", -1, q);
    return b;
}
```

More info was found here:

http://qnalist.com/questions/5650929/mongodb-user-cdriver-cannot-use-or-and-in-find-queries